# Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. - Apache Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to run wordcount example already provided in hadoop on the following env: *(Pseudodistributed mode)*

```
Windows 7
Hadoop 2.7.1
JDK 1.7.x
RAM 4 GB
```

The jps command returns

```
C:\deploy\hadoop-2.7.1>jps
2336 ResourceManager
7500 NameNode
4984 Jps
6900 NodeManager
4940 DataNode
```

The command I use for setting the hadoop heap size

```
set HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=512
```

The command I use from the hadoop home installation directory is

```
bin\yarn jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar wordcount /input /output
```

I see the following stack trace

```
C:\deploy\hadoop-2.7.1>bin\yarn jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-exam
ples-2.7.1.jar wordcount /input /output
15/08/14 22:36:26 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0
:8032
15/08/14 22:36:27 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/08/14 22:36:28 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/08/14 22:36:28 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_14
39571873038_0001
15/08/14 22:36:28 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_14
39571873038_0001
15/08/14 22:36:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://XXX-PC
:8088/proxy/application_1439571873038_0001/
15/08/14 22:36:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1439571873038_0001
15/08/14 22:36:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1439571873038_0001 running in uber
 mode : false
15/08/14 22:36:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/08/14 22:36:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1439571873038_0001 failed with sta
te FAILED due to: Application application_1439571873038_0001 failed 2 times due
to AM Container for appattempt_1439571873038_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode:
1
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://XXX-PC:8088/
cluster/app/application_1439571873038_0001Then, click on links to logs of each a
ttempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1439571873038_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:
722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.la
unchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.C
ontainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.C
ontainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Shell output:         1 file(s) moved.

Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
15/08/14 22:36:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

When I went to the Stderr logs as mentioned in the above stack trace, the actual error came out to be

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
```

When I try to increase `HADOOP_HEAPSIZE` to `1024`, the namenode, datanode and yarn daemons do not start at all and give me the same error of `could not create java virtual machine`

Has someone got the same problem ? How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Just a total guess here because I haven't used Hadoop.  This is typically because I am either requesting an invalid value for memory or there isn't enough memory left to satisfy the request.  Did you look at your available memory on the box to see if 512MB is available to be allocated?

For example
java -Xmx23FD com.test.Test
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx23F
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

java -Xmx999G com.test.Test
Unable to allocate 32735232KB bitmaps for parallel garbage collection for the requested 1047527424KB heap.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by editting the file /etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh like the one below:

```
export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=3072
```

Comment: @user5213409- I got frustrated solving it, that I reinstalled hadoop following each and every step mentioned in building.txt. It went fine, but thanks anyway.